# BigQuery array UNNEST to return distinct values in array?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table that includes an String array field.  For some records, the array can hold duplicate string values.

Is is possible in a BigQuery UNNEST clause to filter out the duplicates so that the UNNEST only returns distinct array string values?

Answer (score 9):

There are many ways to do this. Since you didn't specify a desired input and output, I'll arbitrarily choose one.

Usings `ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT)`:

```sql
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 1 id, ["a", "a", "b", "e", "a", "c", "b", "a"] strings
)


SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT string) strings
FROM data, UNNEST(strings) string
GROUP BY id
```

[image]

Comment: What about if I want the id shows in each row?

Answer (score 5):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * REPLACE(ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT el FROM t.arr AS el) AS arr)
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 col1, 2 col2, ["a", "a", "b", "e", "a", "c", "b", "a"] arr, 3 col3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 5, ["x", "y", "z"], 5
)
SELECT * REPLACE(ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT el FROM t.arr AS el) AS arr)
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

with output

```
Row col1    col2    arr col3     
1   1       2       a   3    
                    b        
                    e        
                    c        
2   4       5       x   5    
                    y        
                    z
```